# Need help creating JPA criteria query

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I'm building my first Java EE web application using Glassfish and JSF. I'm fairly new to the criteria query and I have a query I need to perform but the javaee6 tutorial seems a little thin on examples. Anyway, I'm having a hard time creating the query.

Goal: I want to pull the company with the most documents stored. 
Companies have a OneToMany relationship with Documents. 
Documents has a ManyToOne relationship with several tables, the "usertype" column distinguishes them.

MySQL query:

```
SELECT USERID, COUNT(USERID) AS CNT 
FROM DOCUMENTS 
WHERE USERTYPE="COMPANY" 
GROUP BY USERID 
ORDER BY CNT DESC
```

Thanks

--update--
Based on user feedback, here is what I have so far:

```
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Documents> cqry = cb.createQuery(Documents.class);
        //Intersting Stuff
        Root<Documents> root = cqry.from(Documents.class);
        Expression userid = root.get("userID");
        Expression usertype = root.get("userType");
        Expression count = cb.count(userid);
        cqry.multiselect(userid, count);
        Predicate userType = cb.equal(usertype, "COMPANY");
        cqry.where(userType);
        cqry.groupBy(userid);
        cqry.orderBy(cb.desc(count));
        //more boilerplate
        Query qry = em.createQuery(cqry);
        List<Documents> results = qry.getResultList();
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception Description: Partial object queries are not allowed to maintain the cache or be edited.  You must use dontMaintainCache().
```

Typical error, means nothing to me!

Comment: Try to de-typing the query from CriteriaQuery<Documents> to CriteriaQuery in order to select the count without offending the API. If you also post more infos about the tables / entities I can try some other ways

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your query doesn't return a *complete* entity object as you're only selecting two fields of the given table (this is why you're getting an error that says *yadayadapartialyadayada*).

Your solution is almost right, here's what you need to change to make it work—making it *partial*.

Instead of a plain `CriteriaQuery<...>` you have to create a *tuple* `CriteriaQuery<..>` by calling [`CriteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#createTupleQuery%28%29). (Basically, you can call `CriteriaBuilder.createQuery(...)` and pass [`Tuple.class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html) to it as an argument. `Tuple` is a sort of *wildcard* entity class.)

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq= cb.createTupleQuery();

Root<Documents> root = cq.from(Documents.class);
Expression<Integer> userId = root.get("USERID");
Expression<String> userType = root.get("USERTYPE");
Expression<Long> count = cb.count(userId);

cq.multiselect(userId.alias("USERID"), count.alias("CNT"));
cq.where(cb.equal(userType, "COMPANY");
cq.groupBy(userId);
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(count));

TypedQuery<Tuple> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
for (Tuple t : tq.getResultsList()) {
  System.out.println(t.get("USERID"));
  System.out.println(t.get("CNT"));
}
```

<sub>(Accessing fields of a `Tuple` gave me an error if I didn't use aliases for them (in `multiselect(...)`). This is why I've used aliases, but this can be tackled more cleanly by using JPA 2's *Metamodel API*, which is described in the specification quite thoroughly.</sub> )

The documentation for [`CriteriaQuery.multiselect(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#multiselect%28javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...%29) describes the behaviour of queries using `Tuple` objects more deeply.

Comment: Brilliant! It worked with almost right out of the box. Between this and the article @Mechkov shared I have a much better understanding of criteria queries. Thank you.

Comment: Good answer, helped to solve my problem with the following error `You must use dontMaintainCache()`

Comment: Thanks for your code example. I've learned a lot about jpa criteria queries using tuples (instead of Entities) with it.

Comment: Hi, I want to create an alias for cb.count(userId) and use that alias in subsequent order by by refering to the alias. Is that possible?

Comment: @yaswanth [You do something like this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Tuple_query_examples). You define the alias in the `multiselect` call.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert how do I access the alias later during orderBy?

Comment: @yaswanth Not sure, but in the example I've linked `employee.get("firstName").alias("first")` returns some object for you, reuse that in your `orderBy` clause. Didn't test it tho'.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Hibernate, this should work:

```
ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.groupProperty("userid"))
.add(Projections.property("userid"))
.add(Projections.count("userid"));

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Document.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("usertype",usertype))
.setProjection(pl)
.addOrder(Order.desc("cnt"));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This means using Hiberate, which is out of scope here. You should at least mention this.

Comment: yes, I'm afraid I'm not using Hibernate. albeit I'm starting to wish I were!

Comment: oh, big apologies. Didn't realize that!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this easy tutorial. It uses JPA2 and Criteria

http://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/jpa2-criteria-api

Regards!

Comment: The tutorial you've posted is fine, but the query the OP wants raises an interesting question: is Criteria API really useful when the query returns objects of different types?

Comment: thanks, the tutorial helped me a lot. As far as different types all I need is the id (long).

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped. I used it myself, not too long ago.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constructor to `Documents` with only `userid` and `count` because you will need it on:

```
cqry.multiselect(userid, count);
```