# JPA left outer join using CriteriaBuilder results in error: Partial object queries are not allowed to maintain the cache or be edited

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have the following entity relationships

**Product**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCTS")
public class Product

@Id
@Column(name="product_id")
private long productId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="EMP_NUMBER")
private Employee employee3; 
....
....
```

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee

@Id
@Column(name="EMP_NUMBER")
private String empNumber;

@Column(name="EMP_NAME")
private String employeeName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="employee3")
private List<Product> Product3;

....
....
```

In DAOImpl class I have the following

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Product> cq = 
            cb.createQuery(Product.class);
Root<Product> c = cq.from(Product.class);
Join<Product, Employee> join = 
           c.join(Product_.employee3, JoinType.LEFT);
cq.multiselect(c.get(Product_.productId),        
           c.get(Product_.employee3));
```

However when I execute, I am getting the following errors

> org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
>       Exception Description: Partial object queries are not allowed to maintain
>       the cache or be edited.
>       You must use dontMaintainCache().
>       Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Product )
>           at   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.cannotCachePartialObjects
>        (QueryException.java:388)
>           at     org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.prepareQuery
>         (ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:2160)

What I am trying to achieve is to generate the following SQL

```
SELECT p.product_id,
          emp.emp_name
     FROM products p
          LEFT OUTER JOIN employees emp
             ON (p.emp_number = emp.emp_number)
```

How can I do this and get rid of errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by adding the below mentioned line, might be useful to others if they encounter same problem what been mentioned in question.

```
((org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaQuery)query).getDatabaseQuery().dontMaintainCache();
```

Another better option is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8770341/599528)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria), there are two ways to create a criteria query `createQuery(class)` and `createQuery()` without the parameter. The first method creates a CriteriaQuery cast the result to `class`.

This means to resolve the problem, you can change `CriteriaQuery<Product> cq = cb.createQuery(Product.class);` to this one `CriteriaQuery<Product> cq = cb.createQuery();`.

And then use an `Iterator` to retrieve the result.

```
Iterator products = query.getResultList().iterator();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case and according to this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=303205
The issue happens when you apply a multiselect and don't have a constructor with the selected parameters in the representation object.

For instance if you have

```
Select empNumber,employeeName from Employee
```

Then in your entity or representation object you need a constructor:

```
public Employee(int empNumber, StringemployeeName ){...}
```

Be careful since the order of the parameters matter.