# How to get distinct values of a single column in Criteria API(JPA)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-criteria

Hi I am new for JPA & Criteria API.
I am trying to fetch distinct values of a single column (trying to get only distinct values of TestId).I have below table in my DB.

```
__________________________________
|TestId(Pk) | TestCol(PK) | TestEx|
__________________________________
```

I have below classes
Model Class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "TEST", name = "TEST_TYPE")
public class Test {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TestPK id;

    @Column(nmae = "TestEX")
    private double testEx
}

@Data
@Embeddable
public class TestPK {
    @Column(name = "TestId")
    private String testId;

    @Column(name="TestCol")
    private String testcol
}
```

Repository class

```
public class TestRepoImpl {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Test> getData() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Test> cq = cb.createQuery(Test.class);
        Root<Test> root = cq.from(Test.class);

        // cq.get(Test_.id).get(TestPK_.testId);
        // cq.select(root);
        cq.multiselect(root.get(Test_.id).get(TestPK_.testId));
        cq.distinct(true);
        // List<Tuple> ts = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        List<Test> data = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        return data;
    }
}
```

I am getting below error.

Partial object queries are not allowed to maintain the cache or edited.
You must use dontMaintainCache().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this option as mentioned in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404924/jpa-left-outer-join-using-criteriabuilder-results-in-error-partial-object-queri)  `((org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaQuery)query).getDatabaseQuery().dontMaintainCache();`

Comment: when he is using Hibernate? since he put that in the question title and in the tags

Comment: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.CriteriaQueryImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaQuery...getting this error when trying your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Result is not a list of `Test` but `String`, `private String testId;`

Changing

> `CriteriaQuery<Test> cq = cb.createQuery(Test.class);`

to

> `CriteriaQuery<String> cq = cb.createQuery(String.class);`

and the rest of code correspondingly might help.

Comment: :- I must return Test object if I go with your solution I will get.
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to List<Test> error.

Comment: Please think again what you are after and edit your question to be more precise. You want distinct values of `TestID` but the result should be `Test`. For example if there are two `Test` having the same `TestPK.testId` you might need aggregate or so to pick one of the `Test`s.